# Poisson process with fixed number of events

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

There is a question in a textbook which states the following:

Arrivals are modelled as being from a Poisson process with rate **r** per minute.
Given that 2 arrivals occur in a particular minute, at what time do you expect the first and second arrivals?

Hint: Does your answer depend on **r**?

My thoughts are that, as the arrivals are independent and identically distributed (as assumed from the Poison process from the textbook) and we have 2 in a single minute. We expect the first to occur after 30 seconds and the second after a minute. Is this correct? And why exactly - are the arrivals uniformly distributed over the minute? Or could we say we have a new Poisson process with rate 2 per minute instead of r?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Conditioned on $N$ arrivals occurring in $(0,t]$, the arrival times $T_1,\ldots, T_N$ are uniformly distributed on $(0,t]$. So yes, your reasoning is correct.